# Trying to use Socket.IO namespaces causes 404 polling error

Tags: node.js, socket.io

When I use Socket.IO to connect like normal/default

```
var client = io.connect('http://localhost:466/');
```

It works/connects just fine. No errors in console.

However, when I want to try connecting to a namespace like so

```
var client = io('/adm').connect('http://localhost:466/');
```

I get the following errors

[image]

The admin namepsace is created on the server

```
//start server
var server = require('socket.io').listen(466);

//admin namespace
var adm = server.of('/adm');

adm.on('connection', function(client){
    console.log('adm connection');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was trying

```
var client = io('/adm').connect('http://localhost:466/');
```

instead of

```
var client = io.connect('http://localhost:466/adm');
```

Which I find odd, because the documentation seemed to recommend the first method.

http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#custom-namespaces

Comment: !00% worked for me too. Weird that it's the other way in their docs.